# Минимальное значение из ряда двумерного масива

Tags: c#, массивы, коллекции

Задание: написать програму, которая будет возвращать одномерный масив, который состоит из минимальных значений из каждого ряда, известного двумерного масива.(входной двумерный масив любого размера)

Никак не удаеться написать нужную прогу, которая бы проходила все необходимые тесты.
Пытался по-разному и через разные вариации той проги что сейчас и через коллекции(list<>), хотя тут не уверен правильно ли я использую copyTo или, еще пробовал через, toArray...

Вот что имею на данный момент(не работает):

```
    public static int[] Task4(int[,] array)
{
    int temp = 0;
    int rows = array.GetUpperBound(0) + 1;
    int columns = array.Length / rows;
    int[] resultArray=new int[columns];
    for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < columns; c++)
        {
            if (array[r, c] < array[r, (c + 1)])
            {
                
                temp = array[r, c];
            }
        }
        resultArray[r] = temp;
    }
    return resultArray;
}
```

К сожалению толковой инфы найти не смог, а еще в си шарп как-то уж больно непревычно и не удобно работать с масивами, по сравнению с старшими сишками.
Все упираеться в то как работать с двумерным масивом а не масивом масивов)

UPD: только что обнаружил, что можно проще получить колличество колонок и строк в многомерном масиве:

вместо-

```
    int rows = array.GetUpperBound(0) + 1;
    int columns = array.Length / rows;
```

это-

```
    int rows = array.GetLength(0);
    int columns = array.GetLength(1);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Надо немножко подшаманить ваш код и всё заведется. Пример

```
public static int[] Task4(int[,] array)
{   
    int rows = array.GetLength(0);
    int columns = array.GetLength(1);
    
    int[] resultArray = new int[rows];
    
    for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++)
    {
        int temp = array[r,0];
        for (int c = 1; c < columns; c++)       
            temp = Math.Min(temp, array[r,c]);
        
        resultArray[r] = temp;
    }
    return resultArray;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Если входной массив может быть любого размера, следует предусмотреть варианты пустого массива и массива с пустыми строками.  Тогда вероятно в данном методе придется возвращать не массив целых чисел `int[]`, а массив `int?[]`, так как не всегда могут быть найдены минимумы.

Также в представленном коде проблема с инициализацией `temp`, которая должна выполняться для каждой строки отдельно, и кроме того, нужно всегда сравнивать с уже найденным минимумом.

```cs
public static int?[] Task4(int[,] array) {
    int?[] result = new int?[array.GetLength(0)];

    for (int r = 0; r < array.GetLength(0); r++) {
        int? min = null;
        for (int c = 0; c < array.GetLength(1); c++) {
            if (!min.HasValue || min > array[r, c]) {
                min = array[r, c];
            }
        }
        result[r] = min;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Тесты:

```cs
int[,] empty = {};
int[,] empty2 = {{}, {}};
int[,] good = {{1, 2, 3}, {6, 5, 4}};
Console.WriteLine("[{0}]", string.Join(", ", Task4(empty)));  // -> []
Console.WriteLine("[{0}]", string.Join(", ", Task4(empty2))); // -> [, ]
Console.WriteLine("[{0}]", string.Join(", ", Task4(good)));   // -> [1, 4]
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Я почти к такому же решению пришел изначально, но нахамутал с присваиванием текущего найденого значения к нужному элементу нового масива, и начал крутить. Но конечно не так красиво, и без проверки на пустой входной масив(как-то не подумал об этом)). Про Нуллабл слышал но не знал, тоже есть что изучить. В общем спасибо...